# What do I need to know about using non-portable datatypes on SQL*Loader?

Tags: oracle, integration, bulkinsert, sql-loader

I read the [section in the SQL*Loader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_field_list.htm#i1007642) reference manual and it's a bit over my head.  Our clients are all running x86, so I'm assuming we won't have to worry about byte ordering.  However, we do have some customers running on 32-bit and others running on 64-bit OSes.  What exactly do I need to do to make sure I don't run into any problems because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a problem as the byte orders are the same and size of integers etc will be defined by Oracle and not the OS